# mousewheel doesn't work in chrome (flash)

Tags: jquery, flash, google-chrome, mousewheel

In other browsers it works.

You can check this page for an example where I'm experiencing this issue: http://ilempi.ru/konstruktor

I use [jquery-mousewheel](http://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/) from Brandon Aaron.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    $(function() {
        $('#content').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
            return false;
        });
    });
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: i don't need zoom, i need scroll

Comment: I said inside flash, find scrollpane in it, in chrome you can't scroll by mouse, in onthers you can

Comment: check the screenshot. I scrolled the scrollpane inside Flash with Chrome.

Comment: http://m1310.hizliresim.com/1g/d/thn8y.png

Comment: i mean here http://m1310.hizliresim.com/1g/d/thnff.png , only vertical scroll and only scrolling by mouse wheel

Comment: you can check now, i changed flash, but still mousewheel doesn't work on Chrome

Comment: click on my profile, add me on skype, I can help you there

Comment: Scrolling works for me in Chrome.